# Build a process substitution list for tee

Tags: bash, array, process-substitution

I have a script like this which I use to broadcast commands to several instaces of the postgresql database CLI connected to several different servers. I'm using a hard-coded set of process-substitutions.

```
#!/bin/bash
# names have been changed to protect the guilty
cred="user=dbadmin password=SECRET"
domain=example.com

tee \
   >( psql -X "host=db1.$domain dbname=db1 $cred" ) \
   >( psql -X "host=db2.$domain dbname=db2 $cred" ) \
   >( psql -X "host=db3.$domain dbname=db3 $cred" ) \
   >( psql -X "host=xdb1.$domain dbname=xdb1 $cred" ) \
   > /dev/null    
wait
```

what I would like to do is use a for loop to build up an array of substitutions and pass that array to tee, something like this:

```
tee "${p[@]}" > /dev/null
```

but when I use a loop I get every item in `$p` as `/dev/fd/63` tee gives me
this error for each.

```
tee: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

example non-working code:

```
p=()
for z in db1 db2 db3 xdb1
do
  p+=( >( psql -X "host=$z.$domain dbname=$z $cred" ) )
done
tee "${p[@]}" > /dev/null
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: is there some reason why you need to do this with `tee` rather than, say, a `for` loop?

Comment: I like to paste source for stored procedures in, or type in search queries. a for loop would have to be restarted for each action. some actions are a single line of code, others could be hundereds of lines. plus there's 400ms or more latency opening the SSL connection to the other side of the world.

Comment: Queries etc can be stored in a variable or temp file and re-used multiple times by a script.  Connection latency applies in any case.  IMO simple and robust is always better than flashy and fragile.  And with a for loop around `psql ... &` (or a function which does that in a subshell), it's much simpler to keep track of which connections succeeded and which failed....or just keep re-trying until they succeed.  I'll add an answer with an example.

Comment: the tee system is interactive, with a loop it will be batched instead.

Comment: huh?  batched? interactive?  what you say makes no sense.  there's no restriction in how either version (process subst with tee, or a loop) can be used.

Comment: batched: run the script, enter commands, send eof  (^D) see responses. script terminates.  Interactive: run the script, enter command, see responses, enter command, see responses, send EOF, script terminates.

Comment: btw, i'm not saying that doing it with multiple process substitutions and tee is wrong.  Just that it's not necessary and that what you want to do can be easily achieved without such fragile complication.  It's easy to get stuck on figuring out the details of one solution and end up missing the fact that there are simpler, easier ways to do it.

Comment: what you are saying about batched vs interactive still makes no sense.  what is the distinction you are trying to make here?   that cat somehow can't read stdin?  or that it can only read stdin from the keyboard and not from a file or a pipe?  what's your point?

Comment: it's a timeline thing. cat won't give me feedback.

Comment: that still makes no sense.

Comment: cat won't give me the faadback from psql's output until I close the file.

Comment: and that "feedback" is so essential that you're redirecting multiple copies of that feedback from multiple psql processes to /dev/null?  Look, I get it.  You really want to use your "clever" process-substitution method.  No problem.  Just don't deceive yourself that it's necessary, that it's the only way.  "I'm doing it this way because I want to" is a perfectly valid reason without closing your eyes to alternative methods.

Comment: no. /dev/null is where the output from tee (which is a copy of it's input) , goes to. I'm using dev/null there so that the tee command is symmetrical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because on this line:

```
  p+=( >( psql -X "host=$z.$domain dbname=$z $cred" ) )
```

...bash considers the line to be a complete command. When doing process substitution, the STDIN of the substituted process is closed when the command completes.

There are only 2 ways I can see to do this:

1. `eval`. Lets not go there.
2. `exec`. Lets go there instead:

```
p=()
for z in db1 db2 db3 xdb1
do
  exec {fd}> >(psql -X "host=$z.$domain dbname=$z $cred")
  p+=( $fd )
done
cd /dev/fd && exec tee "${p[@]}" >/dev/null
```

The `{fd}>` syntax causes bash to allocate a new file descriptor, and assign its value to `$fd`, which we then shove into `$p`.
Now `$p` is a bunch of file descriptor numbers, which we have to get `tee` to write into, so we `cd` to `/dev/fd` where the file descriptor numbers are actual files, and then invoke the `tee`.

*(There are numerous other ways to skin the cat, but this is the first and most straightforward that sprang to mind)*

Comment: `exec`!, I never would have thought to look there. in the end I used  `p+=( /dev/fd/$fd )` and avoided the `cd /dev/fd` (for no reason that I can defend logically)

Comment: It works, but I don't understand it.  what does `{fd}>` mean and why doesn't exec terminate the shell ?  is there documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: good idea on the `p+=( /dev/fd/$fd )`. Such a simple way to avoid the `cd` :-). Documentation: `{fd}>` is under paragraph 2 of the [*Redirections* section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), and `exec` is documented under [*shell builtin commands*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins-1) (see the bit about "If no command is specified...").

Comment: I replaced `exec` with `true` and it still worked.  by my reading exec is only needed to manipulate stdin etc.

Comment: `exec` is for more than just STDIN. `exec` manipulates file descriptors of the shell itself, not it's children (commands you run). Using `true` happens to work because it is a shell builtin, and so manipulating the file descriptors of `true` manipulates the file descriptors of the shell. I would not rely upon the behavior though as whether it is supported or not is highly questionable.

Comment: Ah, I see, I tried `/bin/true` and (as you predicted) that did not work. `exec` seems to be a bit like a chimera, but then so is `test`,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of what I meant in my comment.

A for-loop (with repeat until success for each psql command, run in a backgrounded sub-shell).  No need for an array of generated process substitution file-descriptors.

```
cred='user=dbadmin password=SECRET'
domain='example.com'

tf=$(mktemp)
cat > "$tf"

for z in db1 db2 db3 xdb1 ; do
  ( while ! psql -X "host=$z.$domain dbname=$z $cred" < "$tf" ; do : ; done) &
done > /dev/null

# don't delete the tempfile until all jobs have completed
wait

rm -f "$tf"
```

Optionally use `sleep x` rather than `:` in the `while` loop, to have a small delay between each retry attempt.

A smarter version would do more inside the while loop, check the exit status and/or grep stderr to figure out the cause of any failure and respond appropriately.